# How to install a pdf iFilter in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: pdf, sql-server-2000, full-text-indexing, ifilter

I have a database with binary objects that contain documents. A separate column contains the extension (doc, docx, xls, html, txt, ...). I have set up full text indexing and this has worked for years: I can query the contents of the indexed documents.

Now I also want to index pdf files that are stored in the database. This can be done by installing an iFilter. According to Adobe's website, the pdf iFilter is installed when you install the latest version of Acrobat Reader, which I did.

I think I need to do more, because (even after a full reboot of the machine) the pdf iFilter isn't listed with filtreg.exe. I did found some documentation about what needs to be done to enable the iFilter in SQL Server 2005, but these commands do not work in SQL Server 2000.

Has anybody managed to set up full text indexing for pfd in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: You might try [Foxit's PDF iFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/howitwork.php).  Foxit does PDF faster, smarter, better, and less-intrusively than Adobe.  Their support is much more responsive and can probably help you get it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading and installing the separate iFilter everything works.

This is the link:

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611

On this page it says that the info is outdated and that you should just install the newer Adobe Acrobat. This dodn't work for me, installing the old Adobe PDF IFilter v6.0 words.

Comment: The comments on the outdated Adobe page refers to 32bit OSs. If you are using a 64bit OS, here is the [link](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5542) to the newer version.